# springmvc cannot call controller's method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, web.xml

Currently I got a problem when I configure my springmvc web project.

Below is my **web.xml**

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And I defined my **dispatcher-servlet.xml** like this

```
<context:component-scan base-package="xxx.controller"

<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

And in package **xxx.controller** I define a class **TestController**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/api")
public class TestController {


    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello")
    @ResponseBody
    public String hello(){
        System.out.println("comming hello");
        return "hello world";
    }

}
```

Now when I start tomcat, and want to access to *[localhost:8080/testproject/api/hello](http://localhost:8080/testproject/api/hello)*,  The spring informs me

> [10:10:58|WARN |(org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound)]=[No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/testproject/api/hello] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher']

But if I modify the url-pattern in web.xml to

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

It is ok to access to *[localhost:8080/testproject/api/hello](http://localhost:8080/testproject/api/hello)*.  I do not know why this happens. I do want to use **/api/*** rather than **/**.

Could anyone helps me configure the controller path mapping? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling your application to run in /api context when you define the following:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

so to access your controller the URL would have to be *localhost:8080/api/api/hello*

Just get rid of the /api from your dispatcher as you have and then your mapping should automatically default to localhost:8080/api/hello and work.

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Otherwise if you want to run your application in /api context always you have the option of removing @RequestMapping(value="/api") from your controller.
That way it only recognises the mapping on method.

Comment: Sorry but maybe you misunderstood my words.  Currently it works when url-pattern is "/", but not work when url-pattern is "/api/*". I want to make it work under second url-pattern.  Could you tell me how to configure?

Comment: This is correct - If you want the entire app to be served from /api/.. then keep your web.xml as is - but then remove the mapping from your controller @RequestMapping(value="/api") - In your first example you have defined the /api mapping twice (web.xml & @RequestMapping) but you only need it once.

Comment: I see. Now it works according to your suggestion. Thank you very much!